# Subfolder renaming

Tags: htaccess

We have the following problem. We would have following structure:

- domainUrl.tld/Blog1
- domainUrl.tld/Blog2

Our installation path is: wordpress.accounturl.tld

We are able to redirect to accounturl.tld/wordpress .
It's possible to rename the subdirectory?

Our knowledge about htaccess is limited.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to move your wordpress from blog1 to blog2
you will need to do 2 steps

Step 1 - change site url from /wp-admin/options-general.php
WordPress Address (URL)  and Site Address (URL)

Step 2 - rename blog1 folder to blog2 from cpanel and file manager

when you save changes you will not be able to go back blog1
to go back to blog1 you will need to do the same steps